# switch to chrome extension page without the tabs permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension for chrome that shows a results page when a user enters a query from the popup. 
I would like subsequent queries to use the existing results page rather than opening new ones.

I used `chrome.extension.getViews({'type':'tab'})` to get the currently opened extension pages and to pass the query to a javascript function in the open page.

The issue I'm having is switching to that page without requiring the 'tabs' permission.

This snippet of code works well from the background page.

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {selected: true});
});
```

However, tabs.getCurrent requires the 'tabs' permission. Is there a way to do this without the tabs permission?

I could use `chrome.tabs.update` but I don't know how to get the tab id from the view object returned from `chrome.extension.getViews`.

Answer (score 1):

/edit: As appsilers mentioned, not really doable.

If you can instead use `chrome.tabs.create()` to open the required tab, it will also return its tab id upon creation.

Otherwise the only way is to plast a global inside the target context and use `chrome.extension.getViews()` to identify the target and call a focus-stealing function, like `alert()`. But I'd advise against, since it's more like a hack and there isn't really a guarantee this functionality will keep stable between builds.

Comment: -1 Wrong: There is no direct relationship between a [tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab)ID and a `window` object. [`chrome.extension.getViews`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews) returns an array of `window` objects (of the extension's pages).

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this can't be done without the `tabs` permission.  You have correctly identified that `chrome.tabs.update` is the function you need, but without the `tabs` permission, it can only operate on the *currently selected tab* by provifing a `null` tab ID argument. Since you can't supply tab IDs in `chrome.tabs.update` without permission, switching between tabs is not possible.